# URL to a specific Wicket component

Tags: java, http, post, wicket

I have a webpage with a Wicket login form. I want to make a HTTP POST from some other page and be able to login onto my webpage. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Well it can be done. You can read REQUEST (POST & GET) variables/parameters with the

```
 ((WebRequest) getRequest()).getParameters(key)
```

or

```
 getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameters().get(key)
```

and try to perform login in the page constructor. You should use bookmarkable page so mount it or make it stateless. I'm not sure if I answered what you meant in the first place.

HTH,

Marek